# Azure AzVMCustomScriptExtension hangs forever with warning message

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-vm

Using the following script to update a vm with a custom script, I got the a warning message and the command hangs forever.
I don't see where the error could be.

My script would look like the following

```
Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension -Location "LOCATION" -VMName "VMNAME" -Name "EXTENTIONNAME" -StorageAccountName "STOTRAGEACCOUNTNAME" -StorageAccountKey "XXXXXX" -FileName "SCRIPTNAME.ps1" -ContainerName "CONTAINERNAME"| Update-AzVM -Verbose
```

WARNING message :

```
AVERTISSEMENT : No Run File has been assigned, and the Custom Script extension will try to use the first specified File
```

Name as the Run File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CustomScriptHandler.exe process runs as the System account. You can try to solve it by assign permissions to System account

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: Hello @Manu, the system account of the VM or of my local machine?

Comment: This is the account of VM